# Is it possible to auto-press a submit button through page arguments?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, arguments

I have a private system that requires a user to login.  It links to a separate webmail login page that requires users to enter the same credentials twice.  I can pre-fill these fields in with html parameters, but I can't seem to find a way to auto-submit.  Is it possible? How?

Comment: What do you mean with 'html parameters'? Cause what I'm understanding from what you are saying, you are either able to fill the form through PHP yourself, which makes displaying the whole page moot, or you are redirecting a user to another page and use GET/ POST variables to autofill some of the forms. In the case of the latter, you have no control over js scripts that are being triggered (as people suggest in their answers below).

Comment: That's what it sounds like.  Unfortunate, but I guess I see the point.  I'm thinking there is no "right" way to do this, but the CSRF attack would be closest to what I was trying to do.  I think I'm going to just abandon the attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exploit CSRF to log users in, if the webmail isn't protected against CSRF attacks (yes, attack, as automatically submitting forms on 3rd party site is a risk).

```
<form action="https://*address of the webmail login page*" target="_blank">
<input type=hidden 
       name="*find what field names are used for login/pass*"
       value="username, etc">
</form>
<script>document.forms[document.forms.length-1].submit()</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

A lo-tech solution would be to have a javascript fire on page load, which checks for a hidden form field, and based on the value, submits the form using document.forms['<form name>'].submit().

Comment: Form names are deprecated in XHTML, however, so IDs work in that case.

Comment: But how do I have a javascript fire when an external page loads?

Comment: iframes and windows have onload events. what are you opening the external page in? I'm assuming that your page is always around?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the submit method of forms, with Javascript.

Just assign an id to your form:

```
 <form id="form_id">
```

then find it in Javascript and run the submit method

```
var form = document.getElementById('form_id');
form.submit();
```

It's not a good practice but you could use it with window.onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('form_id');
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: But that would require me to have access to the webmail source... right?